# Filter Function Misbehaving: Results Not What I Expected

Tags: javascript, html, angular

How can I filter records in Angular based on time and status code when the navigation button is not working as expected and the max page variable is not being updated?

I am building an Angular application where I need to filter records based on time and status code. However, I am facing two issues:

1. The navigation buttons for moving to the next or previous page are not working as expected. Even when no records are available for the next or previous page, the buttons remain active.
2. The max page variable is not updated when the filter is applied. As a result, the navigation buttons may take the user to pages that do not exist.

I have tried debugging the issue but have not found a solution. I would appreciate any help or suggestions on resolving these issues and successfully filtering the records based on time and status code.

HTML Filter

```
row in filteredErrorRequests = (error_requests | filter: { status_code: selectedStatusCode } | filter: filterByTime) | limitTo: limitRows : (currentPage - 1) * limitRows
```

## JS Controller

```
function checkPreviousPageContent() {
    const previousPageStartIndex = ($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.limitRows;
    const previousPageEndIndex = previousPageStartIndex + $scope.limitRows;
    const previousPageRecords = $scope.error_requests
        .filter(filterByTimeAndStatus)
        .slice(previousPageStartIndex, previousPageEndIndex);

    $scope.previousButtonDisabled = previousPageRecords.length === 0;
}

function checkNextPageContent() {
    const nextPageStartIndex = ($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.limitRows;
    const nextPageEndIndex = nextPageStartIndex + $scope.limitRows;
    const nextPageRecords = $scope.error_requests
        .filter(filterByTimeAndStatus)
        .slice(nextPageStartIndex, nextPageEndIndex);

    $scope.nextButtonDisabled = nextPageRecords.length === 0;
}

function filterByTimeAndStatus(row) {
    return filterByTime(row) && row.status_code === $scope.selectedStatusCode;
}

$scope.error_requests = response.data.error_requests;
$scope.uniqueStatusCodes = getUniqueStatusCodes($scope.error_requests);

// Pagination
$scope.currentPage = 1;
$scope.limitRows = 10;
$scope.maxPage = Math.ceil($scope.error_requests.length / $scope.limitRows);

// Function to go to the first page
$scope.firstPage = function () {
    if ($scope.currentPage !== 1) {
        $scope.currentPage = 1;
        checkPreviousPageContent();
    }
};

// Function to go to the last page
$scope.lastPage = function () {
    if ($scope.currentPage !== $scope.maxPage) {
        $scope.currentPage = $scope.maxPage;
        checkNextPageContent();
    }
};

$scope.previousPage = function () {
    if ($scope.currentPage > 1) {
        $scope.currentPage--;
        checkPreviousPageContent();
    }
};

$scope.nextPage = function () {
    if ($scope.currentPage < $scope.maxPage) {
        $scope.currentPage++;
        checkNextPageContent();
    }
};




// Call the check functions initially to set the button states
checkPreviousPageContent();
checkNextPageContent();

// Call the check functions whenever there is a change in current page or error requests
$scope.$watchGroup(['currentPage', 'error_requests', 'filterByTime', 'selectedStatusCode'], function () {
    checkPreviousPageContent();
    checkNextPageContent();
});
```

Why are navigation buttons still active even though there are no records available for the next page?"

[image]

Comment: You've shared ~70 lines of HTML and ~140 lines of JS. I highly doubt anyone is going to take the time to help you here. Please remember that people on SO are helping out for free. Asking a good question is hard. You need to put the effort into understanding the smallest scope of your issue to isolate it and strip out any unrelevant code so that people digging into your issue have as little things to read and understand. Extra points if you create a minimal repro on Stackblitz. If you let that burden of debunking 100 of lines of raw code to people trying to help you, it's unlikely they will.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will try to lower down the code lines , appreciate your comment